# Illustrator CS3 drawing new objects right above selected object, not at the top of wrapping layer

Tags: adobe-illustrator, layers, shapes, drawing, cs3

I have art work that consists of more than 200 objects.

I need to draw details to objects that are in the middle of wrapping layer. When I draw a new object it is placed  at the top of  wrapping layer, and so above details of work which weren't supposed to be covered. So I have to drag those new objects all the way through to the required position. It's such a waste of time. I do it all the time.

How can I draw new objects right above the selected object, not at the top of object stack?

Comment: You can cut and paste them faster.

Answer (score 0):

Break your artwork into multiple layers, this way, you can show/hide specific parts of the object stack and add new objects easier where you need to.

Permanently lock groups of objects that you rarely need to touch, then only work with those layers that need more frequent updates.

Comment: Thanks I'll try this. But isn't there inbuilt option in IE sc3 for this case?

Comment: Or maybe there is plug-in for this?

Comment: I noticed that I made a mistake in question above. I meant AI sc3 not IE sc3.